# Python multiprocessing, parent process hangs at recv after child process raises exception before send

Tags: python, multiprocessing, connection, pipe, python-multiprocessing

Python is definitely one of the worst languages for parallel processing.

Just finna get the parent process to throw an error when the child process fails. Instead, the parent process hangs at the `recv()` method.

Some code in the child process:

```
try:
    condition.acquire()
    x = 0/0
    pipeConn2.send('test data')
    condition.notify_all()
    condition.release()
except:
    pipeConn2.close() # expect this to raise exception in parent process per docs
    condition.notify_all()
    condition.release()
```

Some code in the parent process:

```
try:
    condition0.acquire()
    condition0.wait()
    pipe0Conn1.recv() # hangs here instead of raising exception
except:
    # handle exception
```

Comment: You should start off with visiting [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). More specifically, please post a complete but [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. something that can be copied and pasted and run without any additions. How could I even be sure that `pipe0Conn1.recv()` is being executed and not still blocking on the previous `acquire()`, for example?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have a race condition. Even if you eliminate the divide-by-zero exception and never close the connection, the call to `recv` in the main process will hang anyway if the subprocess is first to acquire the implicit lock associated with the underlying `condition` instance (I am giving you the benefit of the doubt that `condition` and `condition0` *do* reference the same instance.

The problem is that if your subprocess is the first to acquire the lock, it will send its data, do its notifying, release the lock and terminate. The main process will then be able to acquire the lock for the first time and then call `wait`. But when it calls `wait` it releases the lock and implicitly waits for a notification that has already occurred and will hang indefinitely on the `wait`. You can verify this by commenting out the statement `x = 0/0` and inserting `import time; time.sleep(.5)` as the first statements within the main process's `try` block to ensure that the subprocess acquires the condition lock first.

Just to get past that problem I am using an `Event` instance to pause the subprocess until the main process signals to it that it has acquired the condition lock.

I have verified that there does indeed seem to be a problem with the main process hanging when the subprocess does a close on the connection. This, however, does work correctly when I substitute multithreading for multiprocessing. So there *appears* to be a bug in Python. I have tested this on Windows with Python 3.8.5 and Linux with Python 3.9.7.

This is what a minimal, reproducible example looks like:

```py
USE_THREADING = False

from multiprocessing import Pipe
if USE_THREADING:
    from threading import Thread as SubTask, Condition, Event
else:
    from multiprocessing import Process as SubTask, Condition, Event

def foo(condition, pipeConn2, acquired_event):
    try:
        acquired_event.wait()
        condition.acquire()
        x = 0/0
        pipeConn2.send('test data')
    except:
        pipeConn2.close() # expect this to raise exception in parent process per docs
    finally:
        condition.notify_all()
        condition.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    condition = Condition()
    pipeConn1, pipeConn2 = Pipe()
    # Ensure that our main process/thread is first to acquire the condition:
    acquired_event = Event()
    p = SubTask(target=foo, args=(condition, pipeConn2, acquired_event))
    p.start()
    try:
        condition.acquire()
        # Now allow the subprocess/subthread to proceed to try to acquire the lock:
        acquired_event.set()
        condition.wait()
        print('Receiving data ...')
        data = pipeConn1.recv()
        print(f"Data received: '{data}'")
    except Exception as e:
        print('Exception:', type(e))
    p.join()
```

Prints:

```
Receiving data ...
```

Just as an aside, yours is not a particularly realistic example. A `Pipe` is essentially a single consumer/single producer communication vehicle unless you build on top of it a lot of "scaffolding" and then you might as well just use one of the `Queue` variants. Realistically then a process or thread would just be doing a blocking receive on the connection and your producer could write a special *sentinel* object (`None` often suffices) to signal that this is the "end of file". There is really no need to do an explicit close on a connection; it will be closed when it is garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, that the [`Parent Pipe Connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pipe) was waiting indefinetly. Instead of using [`Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Lock), I used the [`Parent Pipe Connection . Poll`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.connection.Connection.poll) function with returns a boolean value depending on if there is anything to recieve. Some Examples:-
Without [`Poll`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.connection.Connection.poll) -

```py
try:
    pipe0Conn1.recv() # Waits indefinetly (until it recieves)
except EOFError as e:
    # handling not recieved
except:
    # some other exception
```

Without [`Poll`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.connection.Connection.poll) -

```py
try:
    if pipe0Conn1.poll() is True:
        pipe0Conn1.recv() # Doesn't wait indefinetly (immediate recieve)
    else:
        # Some other code for handling nothing recieved
except EOFError as e:
    # handling not recieved
except:
    # some other exception
```

PS: Its my first answer on stackoverflow, and I am really sorry about any grammatical, format, code mistakes. Please comment any feedback if you wish.